# How does dictionary initialization work in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, constructor

```
var maxDictionary = new Dictionary<int, double> { { 10, 40000 } };
```

In the above code, does the compiler uses a constructor? Or does the compiler create a KeyValuePair and add to the dictionary? I'm trying to understand how the compiler interprets it.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, compiler uses default parameterless constructor and then adds all values specified in collection initializer via [Dictionary.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7z0zy8k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. As Jon pointed, your code is compiled into

```
Dictionary<int, double> maxDictionary2;
Dictionary<int, double> maxDictionary;

maxDictionary2 = new Dictionary<int, double>();
maxDictionary2.Add(10, 40000.0);
maxDictionary = maxDictionary2;
```

Generated IL:

```
.maxstack 3
.locals init (
     [0] class [mscorlib]Dictionary`2<int32, float64> maxDictionary,
     [1] class [mscorlib]Dictionary`2<int32, float64> maxDictionary2)
L_0000: nop 
L_0001: newobj instance void [mscorlib]Dictionary`2<int32, float64>::.ctor()
L_0006: stloc.1 
L_0007: ldloc.1 
L_0008: ldc.i4.s 10
L_000a: ldc.r8 40000
L_0013: callvirt instance void [mscorlib]Dictionary`2<int32, float64>::Add(!0, !1)
L_0018: nop 
L_0019: ldloc.1 
L_001a: stloc.0
```

I.e. created dictionary assigned to temporary variable `maxDictionary2`, filled with values, and only then reference to created and filled dictionary is copied to `maxDictionary` variable.

Keep in mind that you can specify any other constructor, if you don't want to use parammeterless one. E.g. you can use one which sets initial capacity:

```
var maxDictionary = new Dictionary<int, double>(10) { { 10, 40000 } };
```

Comment: Well sort of. Logically the assignment to `maxDictionary` comes *after* the `Add` call. This is visible if you're actually reassigning to an existing variable, where the collection initializer can use the existing variable's value, and it refers to the *old* collection.

Comment: Hmm, but if i decompile it using DotPeak, it still generates: new Dictionary<int, double>()      {        {          10,          40000.0        }      }

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for good note. Yes, I can see that in reflector. Is there any particular reason to create additional variable for dictionary?

Comment: @Uriil That's because DotPeek is "smart" and tries to give you idiomatic C# instead of a naive decompile. Just like it will give you a `foreach` loop instead of calling `GetEnumerator()` etc. directly.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy: Yes - the whole of the right hand side of the assignment operator logically executes before the assignment operator itself does. That's the way *all* of C# works. In some cases the compiler could optimize it away - and I think it might do so - but I like to think of the *logical* operation of collection initializers.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Yes, there is, If you add number of items and one throws exception you shouldn't get half baked dictionary isn't it?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That's also a good observation. Basically, making the RHS evaluate before the assignment avoids a whole lot of unintuitive behaviour / gotchas.

Comment: @millimoose Thanks, I forgot that. Updated my answer :)

Comment: @JonSkeet, like one person has already pointed out in their answer, most likely there are two reasons to use a temporary variable to store the dictionary being initialized rather than just assigning it to the right variable/field: because if the real destination was a field, it'd be slower to read for every `Add` call when compared to reading a local variable; also, if while evaluating the right–hand expression (the dictionary instantiation) or when calling the `Add` method an exception were thrown, the dictionary would have been left in an unpredictable state

Comment: At this point, @JonSkeet, I just wonder why the stack wasn't used in place of an additional local variable, but I guess it would've been worse performance–wise to duplicate the last operand in the stack before every `Add` call, rather than just reading the same local variable. However, this might be an implementation–detail of the compiler that'd also result differently according to the actual runtime implementation (if a stack–based hardware machine existed, it may have been faster at duplicating and popping out of the stack than accessing a local variable, who knows?)

Comment: @DavideCannizzo: In additional local variable *is* using the stack, effectively. That's where the local variable would be stored. I'm happy to leave it to the JIT to optimize. As another side-effect when assigning to a field, if the initializer refers to the field itself, you don't want it to have been assigned at the start...

Comment: @JonSkeet, you gave one more reason why a temporary variable is used. When talking about the stack, however, I was referring to the CLR evaluation stack, not the stack pointer of a given architecture. Also, as Eric Lippert pointed out (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47645426) local variables are not necessarily stored in the stack in the jitted machine code.

Comment: @JonSkeet, maybe I misunderstood your latest comment — with "In additional local variable is using the stack, effectively" you might have been talking about local variables being pushed into the stack. That's true, obviously, but my argument was whether duplicating the last operand is slower than pushing a local variable into the stack or not, to which I cannot answer as I'm not familiar with the C# JIT compiler implementation, and I don't think a benchmark would be meaningful in this regard

Comment: @DavideCannizzo: I was talking about the CLR stack frame that contains all the local variables within a method; I do see what you mean about that being slightly different to the evaluation stack itself. Completely agree that it may not be the "machine code stack" as it were, because of what the JIT compiler does. I suspect that emitting code to use the local variables is simpler for the compiler *and* easier to debug, and just lets the JIT compiler do the right thing. As you say, it would be hard to write a meaningful benchmark - suggesting it's probably a negligible difference.

Answer (score 7):

```
var maxDictionary = new Dictionary<int, double> { { 10, 40000 } };
```

Here is the generated IL of the program

```
IL_0001:  newobj      System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.Double>..ctor
IL_0006:  stloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0007:  ldloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_0008:  ldc.i4.s    0A 
IL_000A:  ldc.r8      00 00 00 00 00 88 E3 40 
IL_0013:  callvirt    System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Int32,System.Double>.Add
IL_0018:  nop         
IL_0019:  ldloc.1     // <>g__initLocal0
IL_001A:  stloc.0     // maxDictionary
```

Clearly it uses parameterless constructor and calls `Add` method. Label "IL_0013" shows call to `Add` method

Equivalent c# code would be

```
Dictionary<int, double> maxDictionary;
Dictionary<int, double> temp = new Dictionary<int, double>();
temp.Add(10, 40000.0);
maxDictionary = temp;
```

Worth noting that compiler uses `temp` variable, I can see two reasons for that

1. To make sure you don't get half baked dictionary when it encounters an exception.
2. You don't expect the compiler to read the field for just creating a new instance and assigning. Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Other people have already pointed out **how** the C# compiler emits calls to the `Add` method of a `Dictionary`. However, no one has still talked about **when** the C# compiler emits those calls.

Well, it has nothing to do with the `System.Collections.Dictionary` (or `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`) class. This feature is called collection initialization, as it requires the target instance to be of a type that implements the `System.Collections.IEnumerable` interface. The only requirement more is the presence of a method named `Add`, not even its signature nor its return type are ever considered.

When the `Add` method expects one only argument, initialization looks like this:

```
class Foo : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(string a)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

var myFoo = new Foo
{
    "item 1",
    "item 2",
    "item 3",
    "item 4",
    "item 5"
};
```

The above code represents exactly what happens with the `System.Collections.List` (or `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>`) class, as it implements `System.Collections.IEnumerable`.

When the `Add` method expects two arguments or more, like it is for a dictionary, then every item must have values for each parameter of that method, so it was designed to have those values within braces and looks like this:

```
class Foo : IEnumerable
{
    public void Add(string a, int b, bool c)
    {

    }

    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

var myFoo = new Foo
{
    { "item 1", 3, false },
    { "item 2", 1, true },
    { "item 3", 4, true },
    { "item 4", 1, true },
    { "item 5", 5, true },
};
```

**For curious people:**

The code in this answer includes a funny thing that is related to circles. Will anyone ever discover it?